# Creating a simple model to collect data on effects of EMI Shielding

Tags: electromagnetism

I'm doing physics extended essay for IB, and my research question is "To what extent do different conductive materials utilized in electromagnetic interference shielding effectively prevent unwanted interference and safeguard sensitive electronic components?", now I have to create a model to collect data, however I'm struggling to find any waves to replace electromagnetic.

Is there any suggestion for creating a simple model on verifying EMI shielding effectiveness?

*Sorry if my question is confusing.